# TestNG - Is it possible to use AnnotationTransformer with dataProvider?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, testng, testng-dataprovider

I am writing functional tests using TestNG, and I have a few dozens of similar tests with different data. I would like to use DataProvider to reduce repeating code.

But some of those tests pass, some fail (due to a known defect). I want to disable failing tests until they are fixed, so they don't spoil whole picture of test run.

I see that AnnotationTransformer can change test annotations dynamically. Can AnnotationTransformer disable test only with some of the data sets? Or will it disable test with all provided data and it is better not to change anything?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply put these failing tests in a group, say "broken", and exclude that test from your runs? Much simpler than using an annotation transformer, and the reports will show you which groups were excluded, so there is no risk to miss any when comes the time to ship.

Comment: At the moment all of these tests a separate methods, and failing ones are put in a group that is excluded in xml-file. 
The thing is that not all of these tests are failing. Say, we have 20 possible variants of data (that can be passed through dataProvider), and tests with 10 of them are failing, another 10 - pass. I need to monitor those passing variants so the behaviour of application is clear. What should I do in this case? Should I use dataProvider with some hack or is it better to leave everything as it is now?